# Active directory authentication using python

Tags: python, authentication, active-directory

I need to provide an AD authentication for a project and although I know this can be done using LDAP, I am concerned about the security of my service since passwords have to be transferred in plain text.

More specifically, I need to authenticate the user and return some groups from the AD (roles)

How is this accomplished in grand-scale applications? LDAPS? Is there a better mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to authenticate to LDAP and want it to be secure, use ldaps (ldap w/ ssl) or ldap with [startTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol#StartTLS) enabled.   Slightly old, but still relevant: [Security best practices in LDAP](http://people.apache.org/~elecharny/ldapcon/Andrew%20Findlay-paper.pdf)

For those using ldap at scale, or really at all, ldaps and ldap w/ starttls are your options for security.